# Freebsd change default Internet channel route

Tags: freebsd, internet, route, channel

I have two Internet channel and Gateway on freebsd. When I switch channel with the command `route change default chan2`, the command `netstat -nr` shows changed default route. But `traceroute` shows that the packets go through the old route chan1.

**Example:**

```
$netstat -nr 
Routing tables Internet: Destination Gateway  Flags    Refs   Use  Netif Expire
                         default     xxx.xxx.183.54 US 0 8432    em3

$sudo route change default xxx.xxx.144.125 
change net default: gateway> xxx.xxx.144.125

$netstat -nr
Routing tables Internet: Destination Gateway Flags Refs Use  Netif Expire
                         default     xxx.xxx.144.125   US  2  16450  em3
```

BUT

```
$ traceroute 8.8.8.8
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  xxx.xxx.183.53 (xxx.xxx.183.53)  0.527 ms  0.415 ms  0.483ms
```

All works if I run the following combination:

> $sudo route del default
>
> $sleep 10
>
> $sudo route add default xxx.xxx.144.125

Comment: What version are you running (`uname -a` should show)?

Comment: FreeBSD 8.2-RELEASE FreeBSD 8.2-RELEASE #0: Fri Apr 15 12:45:40 MSD 2011     root@grs.ru:/usr/src/sys/amd64/compile/IXI_8_2_PF_x64  amd64

Comment: The gateway in your first routing table and the first hop in your traceroute aren't the same (.53 vs .54) - did you copy and paste or re-type this? Can you also post the full output of `netstat -rnf inet`?

Comment: traceroute running from my GW (.54), .53 is IP first provider`s device.

Comment: Are both gateways connected to the same interface?  The netstat -rn output you show has em3 for both gateways.  Perhaps you need to specify the -interface option to the route change command.

Comment: Clear the ARP cache `arp -d -a` and/or routing tables `route flush` before adding the new default route. Possibly the kernel/user space is consulting stale data.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have something else in your routing tables. Have you tried to look at the route with the route command to see if it's using the default route or something else ?

route show 8.8.8.8

It should show default...

route  show 8.8.8.8

```
 route to: dns.google
destination: default 
mask: default 
gateway: your-gateway.whatever 
  fib: 0 
interface: ixl3 flags:
<UP,GATEWAY,DONE,STATIC>
recvpipe sendpipe ssthresh rtt,msec mtu weight expire 
      0        0        0        0  1500   1     0
```

---

if it's not showing default and you need the ip it's use route -n

Answer (score 0):

If you use `route change` command, you need to restart network service
to apply the changes, e.g.:

```
$ sudo /etc/rc.d/netif restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you have a cached route to 8.8.8.8? The full output of `netstat -nr` would show that. If so you would need to remove it before testing your change - either that route specifically or you could `route flush` and then add rather than change the default gateway (but bare in mind this will interrupt non-local traffic whilst between the two commands if you go that way).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why I don't recognize the output from your netstat -rn command, but I'm used to seeing a NETMASK there.

Not sure why your netmasks aren't showing up, but since they're not, you might have completely incorrect netmasks and the certainly could be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the output of the ping command, it seems that you are targeting the local IP address, rather than the remote gateway.

So if xxx.xxx.183.54/29 is assigned to your FreeBSD node (as seen under ifconfig) you need to use the next hop IP address which looks like it could be xxx.xxx.183.5**3**/29. The same may be true in that the xxx.xxx.144.125 address is the address assigned to a local interface.

As an example, I have a machine with the following:

```
ifconfig:
  em0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
  inet xxx.xxx.123.99 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast xxx.xxx.xxx.255
  
  em1: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
  inet xxx.xxx.234.99 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast xxx.xxx.xxx.255

netstat -rn
  Destination        Gateway            Flags     Netif Expire
  default            xxx.xxx.123.254    UGS       em0
```

In my example above , all traffic is currently going out of the em0 interfacec towards the ISPs #1 Router IP (xxx.xxx.123.254) as the next hop.

If I wanted to route all traffic out of em1, rather than em0 I would use:
`$sudo route change default xxx.xxx.234.1`, if xxx.xxx.234.1 was my ISPs #2 router IP address on that LAN segment.

I would also suggest checking to see if dhclient is running with either ISP, as it maybe installing routes unbeknown to you in the background.